# embedded webserver for MCU with RESP API support

Tags: rest, websocket, webserver, freertos, lwip

I'm developing a project where I use FreeRTOS+lwip on a Cortex M7 MCU.
I need a web server that supports management of REST APIs, websockets, and possibly https (via Mbed TLS or WolfSSL).
Excluding the webserver integrated in lwip (that if I understand well doesn't meet some requirements) and the one that NXP integrates in the SDK, can you suggest me some open source web server that can be integrated in my project?

regards